# AppleMusicKit SDK / Sample Project - UserToken issue

Tags: swift, apple-musickit

I'm currently experimenting with the `Adding-Content-to-Apple-Music` code found here: https://developer.apple.com/musickit/

I'm using:
XCode 9 beta 2, 
iOS 11 (iPhone 5s)

I have a developer token (which works when I query the Apple Music API searching songs etc...) but I now want to use this to exchange for a User Token so I can perform write actions against my Apple Music account.

The test app fires up and allows me to request authentication. From this I can see:

- MPMedia Library - Authorized
- SKCloudServicesController - Authorized
- Capabilities:

  - Add to Cloud Music Library
  - Music Catalog Playback

My next obvious step is to use the developer token to gain the user token. However, as soon as I call the following:

`cloudServiceController.requestUserToken(forDeveloperToken: developerToken, completionHandler: completionHandler)`

i see the following error in the `completionHandler`  - can anyone help?

2017-07-14 10:05:39.179300+0100 Adding-Content-to-Apple-Music[1326:172100] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

2017-07-14 10:05:40.635503+0100 Adding-Content-to-Apple-Music[1326:172299] [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)""

2017-07-14 10:05:40.636449+0100 Adding-Content-to-Apple-Music[1326:172100] SSAccountStore: Failed to fetch the backing accounts. error = Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"

2017-07-14 10:05:40.800933+0100 Adding-Content-to-Apple-Music[1326:172297] [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)""

**2017-07-14 10:05:40.801259+0100 Adding-Content-to-Apple-Music[1326:172299] SSAccountStore: Failed to fetch the backing accounts. error = Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=9 "(null)"
An error occurred when requesting user token: The operation couldn’t be completed. (SKErrorDomain error 1.)**

In `Settings > iTunes & App Store` on my device I am logged in with my Apple ID. Same goes for Apple Music too.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the steps you went though to generate your developer token? I've done all the steps on the developer portal and have my key. I'm not too familiar with JWT. Do you have to include a library of some sort in the iOS app to generate this?

Comment: I found this which includes the steps: https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator

Comment: @JasonC.Howlin that's the one Jason - helpful tutorial on the GH page too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on this:

I also posted about this over on the Apple dev forums. It was an error on their side and now appears to be fixed. I can get a `UserToken` in both iOS 10 and 11 now.

Comment: Have the issue currenty with iOS 11.3 same error as you've got :/

Comment: 11.3.1, same issues since several days.

Comment: Not working for iOS 11.3, is there a solution to this?

Comment: not seen any issues here. can you access the Apple Music API with your Developer Token? If not there could be an issue with that preventing you from creating the User Token