# Apple Music kit User token Issue iOS 11 Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-musickit

I'm trying to get familiar with Apple's Music Kit SDK using the sample Xcode project 'Adding-content-to-Apple-Music' that Apple provides

I'm running into this issue where the sample is not able to get hold of a usertoken. I made sure I have the right developer token. I see in the 'Authorize' section-

MPMediaLibrary: Authorized

SKCloudServiceController: Authorized

Capabilities: Music Catalog Subscription Eligible

this is using: Xcode 9.2, iOS 11.2, Swift 4

```
2018-03-22 23:24:51.109208-0400 Adding-Content-to-Apple- 
Music[33233:12833831] [MC] Reading from private effective user 
settings.

2018-03-22 23:24:55.193343-0400 Adding-Content-to-Apple- 
Music[33233:12833831] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we 
can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction

An error occurred when requesting user token: The operation couldn’t be 
completed. (SKErrorDomain error 1.)
```

Can someone please help?

I've looked at the same question asked by others here:

[apple musickit user token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672398/apple-musickit-user-token)

[I am try to get user token for apple music API, i have already generated valid developer token from python terminal commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353686/i-am-try-to-get-user-token-for-apple-music-api-i-have-already-generated-valid-d)

[Error getting a userToken for Apple Music SDK with JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721314/error-getting-a-usertoken-for-apple-music-sdk-with-jwt)

[How to Create a Apple Music User Token outside iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162986/how-to-create-a-apple-music-user-token-outside-ios)

[AppleMusicKit SDK / Sample Project - UserToken issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099905/applemusickit-sdk-sample-project-usertoken-issue)

I have also looked for an answer on the Apple developer forum with no luck. Also tried posting this on the Apple developer forum but my post was rejected by a moderator.

Thank you.

Comment: Good question, I see, that the problem is really being existing.